# open new page in ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have following ajax call which I used to call the controller method.

```
self.ajax = function (url, postData, callBack, callBackParam) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function () {
                alert();
            },
        });
    }
```

When I execute it, Its working fine and this goes to the relevant url that I mentioned in the function. Following is my controller method.

```
 public ActionResult Details()
{
 return View();
}
```

In this controller I am calling a separate view. What I want is to open the new page by using this view. Is it possible in this scenario?

Because in here final ajax response is comes to the success code so I dont see any way to open this as separate page.

Thanks.

Comment: you want to open in new page or same window?

Comment: You want to open a new page or put this partial view in the current page ?

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page.

Comment: I want to open a separate page.I dont want to put this partial view in the current page

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Ok...That means I have to use separate way to achieve this scenario?

Comment: No , its not possible in this scenario.

Comment: Opening a page in new separate tab/window requires `target="_blank"` parameter at the header, and calling a view instead of partial one.

Comment: Just make a normal submit, and in your POST method, redirect to a method that displays your view - there is no point in using ajax to submit the data if you want to go to a different view

Comment: I think you should use this after normal POST submit: `return Content("window.open('[target.address.domain]')")` (or return `JavaScriptResult` which contains script) to open new window.

Comment: just notice: if you use "get" type, `data: postData` not needed in ajax parameters, it should be used in "post" type

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right,

You will be having a Controller method, to which you call 'GET' with essential parameters

```
public ActionResult PostMethod(YourModel Object)
{
    return Json(true);
}
```

And another method which return view

```
public ActionResult Details() 
{   
    return View(); 
}
```

So In your ajax call, You will be calling `PostMethod` to which you are passing 
the parameter, and on its success, the page `Details` will be opened in a new window.

```
self.ajax = function (url, postData, callBack, callBackParam) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        data: postData,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data){
                window.open("url of Details View", "_blank"); // site.com/controller/Details
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert();
        },
    });
}
```